# Excel. Проблема адресации ячеек после копирования строк

Tags: excel, vba

В одном Excel документе одна страница является некоторым набором шаблонов. Эти шаблоны в зависимости от выбора пользователя копируются с помощью VBA в определенные места документа. При этом встретился с проблемой адресации ячеек в следующим случае:

В шабоне:

```
A1: „некоторое значение“
B2: „$A1“ - ссылается на эту ячейку, причем колонка имеет абсолютный пусть, строка релятивный.
```

Эти две строки копируются (VBA) в произвольные строки документа. Допустим в 5 строку. Тогда:

```
A5: „некорое значение“
B6: ссылается на A5 (5 строка устанавливается автоматически из-за относительного пути – без знака $)
```

Теперь уже вторая строка копируется и добавляется ниже. Т.е. получаем примерно следующее содержание:

```
A5: „Значение“
B6: «=$A5»
B7: „=$A6“
```

Проблема в этой 7 строке, нужно что бы b7 тоже ссылался бы на A5. Но я не могу сделать в шаблоне ссылку фиксированной (типа $A$1). Как такое можно реализовать в шаблоне, чтобы после копирования не нужно было как-то «вручную» или из VBA подправлять ссылки.

Comment: Прям какое-то "тут играем, тут не играем..." получается. Если копирует VBA - вот он пусть и смотрит, где ближайшее, но выше, "значение", а не формула, и правит текущую формулу после копирования.

Comment: Эти шаблоны редактируют конечные пользователи, которые с VBA не очень

Comment: Если без корректировки ссылок, то только с усложнением формулы. А формула может быть разной и ее реализация завсит  от расположения данных как  на исходном листе, так и на листе вставки. Покажите пример, отражающий структуру данных.